# Compound Duration to Seconds

Tags: php, time

Trying to convert Compound Duration to Seconds in php:

examples:

1 hour 3 mins

2 hours 1 min

5 mins

1 min

I have tried strtotime(), is there another built in function to convert to seconds?

Thanks for any help!

Code I have tried $seconds= strtotime('5 mins');

Comment: *"Trying to convert"* - I don't see code that you tried.

Comment: I am trying to convert human readable time to seconds.

Comment: R.SABO I've retracted my vote, you're correct. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1** (robust)**: String together functions from [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval)** to achieve the functionality you require:

```
<?php
    $interval = "2 hours";
    echo date_create('@0')->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($interval))->getTimestamp();
?>
```

<sup>[PHP playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/moMXmLDWI81yZm8Z)</sup>

[`date_create('@0')`](http://php.net/date_create) creates a new `DateTime` object with timestamp `0`, then adds the time interval that PHP creates using whatever you've specified for `$interval` using [`DateInterval::createFromDateString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php). Finally, you [get and echo the Unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) to output the number of seconds you've added.

---

**Option 2** (simpler)**: Stick with `strtotime()` with some math** to get to the correct answer:

```
<?php
    $interval = "2 hours"
    echo strtotime("+" . $interval)-time();
?>
```

<sup>[PHP playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/h0tYkfNnV0weoRYe)</sup>

Leveraging the knowledge you already have regarding [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime), offset by the current Unix time to retrieve the number of seconds in the strtotime function.

Comment: Nice, did not know of this :)

Comment: According to the manual, `date_create — Alias of DateTime::__construct()` is it possible to achieve the same with `DateTime::`?

Comment: @James It certainly should, if that fits your code style more.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use strtotime.
Just use "+" . $time and it will assume you mean that much time in the future.
Then just subtract whatever the Unix time is and you are left with the calculation of the string in seconds.

```
$arr = ['1 hour 3 mins','2 hours 1 min','5 mins','1 min'];

foreach($arr as $val){
    $seconds =0;
    $temp = explode(" ", trim($val));
    //Use array_chunk to group the number with unit.
    foreach(array_chunk($temp,2) as $part){
        $seconds +=strtotime("+" . implode(" ", $part)) - time();
    }
    echo $seconds . "\n";
 }
```

Outputs:

```
3780
7260
300
60
```

https://3v4l.org/n7W3L

Comment: Note that whitespace in the wrong place in the string will break this approach. such as `$arr = ['1 hour 3 mins ']`

Comment: That can be handled with a trim. No big deal.

Comment: Sure, it's just an additional function call :) was just pointing it out